# Debugging SSR on server (production) using console.log nuxt.js (2.0)

Tags: debugging, nuxt.js

In my store index.js file I am doing a console log of an API response (need to debug a crucial issue) - this works on my local (displayed in browser's inspect > console).

I've deployed this change to production however it is not displaying anything (nuxt is running on aws lambda so cannot ssh into the box to view console output to the CLI).

Is there a way to get it showing in the browser's console output for a production environment?

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "vueapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My App",
  "author": "Me",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "analyze": "nuxt build --analyze",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook",
    "deploy": "npm run build && sls deploy"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^0.1.9",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.3.6",
    "@nuxtjs/gtm": "^2.3.0",
    "@nuxtjs/sentry": "^4.1.2",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^1.4.0",
    "browser-detect": "^0.2.28",
    "hooper": "^0.3.4",
    "lg-thumbnail": "^1.1.0",
    "lightgallery.js": "^1.1.3",
    "mapbox-gl": "^1.10.0",
    "nuxt": "^2.0.0",
    "nuxt-fontawesome": "^0.4.0",
    "nuxt-i18n": "^6.6.1",
    "nuxt-start": "^2.12.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "serverless-apigw-binary": "^0.4.4",
    "serverless-http": "^2.0.1",
    "v-click-outside": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-cookies": "^1.7.0",
    "vue-light-gallery": "^1.0.1",
    "vue-mapbox": "^0.4.1",
    "vue-scrollto": "^2.18.1",
    "vue-slick-carousel": "^1.0.6",
    "vue-youtube-embed": "^2.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@nuxtjs/proxy": "^1.3.3",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.3.17",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^5.3.17",
    "@storybook/addons": "^5.3.17",
    "@storybook/vue": "^5.3.17",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-preset-vue": "^2.0.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "serverless-domain-manager": "^3.2.1",
    "serverless-offline": "^4.10.0",
    "serverless-plugin-warmup": "^4.9.0"
  }
}
```

nuxt.config.js

```
nuxtConfig = {
    mode: "universal",

    /*
     ** Remove telemetry which requires user input https://github.com/nuxt/telemetry#opting-out
     */
    telemetry: false,

    /*
     ** Headers of the page
     */
    head: {
        title: process.env.npm_package_name || "",

        meta: [
            { charset: "utf-8" },
            {
                name: "viewport",
                content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
            },
            { name: "msapplication-TileColor", content: "#b91d47" },
            {
                name: "msapplication-TileImage",
                content:
                    "https://static.myapp.com/static/app/favicons/mstile-144x144.png"
            },
            {
                name: "msapplication-config",
                content:
                    "https://static.myapp.com/static/app/favicons/browserconfig.xml"
            },
            { name: "theme-color", content: "#ffffff" }
        ],
    },

    /*
     ** Customize the progress-bar color
     */
    loading: { color: "#900" },

    /*
     ** Global CSS
     */
    css: ["@/assets/scss/app/base.scss"],

    /*
     ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
     */
    plugins: [
        "~/plugins/http.js",
        "~/plugins/filters.js",
        "~/plugins/cookies.js",
        "~/plugins/lightGallery.client.js",
        { src: "~/plugins/youtube.js", mode: "client" },
        { src: "~/plugins/vClickOutside.js", mode: "client" },
        // { src: "~/plugins/mapbox.js", mode: "client" }
    ],

    /*
     ** Nuxt.js dev-modules
     */
    buildModules: [
        // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/nuxt-tailwindcss
        "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss",
        "@nuxtjs/gtm"
    ],

    /*
     ** Nuxt.js modules
     */
    modules: [
        // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
        // https://nuxt-community.github.io/nuxt-i18n/options-reference.html
        // https://medium.com/@denizgentrk/nuxt-js-and-sanity-io-full-localization-solution-1239e822fd9b
        "@nuxtjs/axios",

        // Sentry error logging
        "@nuxtjs/sentry",
        "vue-scrollto/nuxt",

        // Languages (refs: https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp and https://nuxt-community.github.io/nuxt-i18n/routing.html#ignore-routes)
        [
            "nuxt-i18n",
            {
                strategy: "prefix",
                encodePaths: false,
                // locales: ['en', 'de', 'es', 'fr', 'pt'],
                locales: [
                    { code: "en", name: "English", file: "en.js" },
                    { code: "de", name: "Deutsche", file: "de.js" },
                    { code: "es", name: "Español", file: "es.js" },
                    { code: "fr", name: "Français", file: "fr.js" },
                    { code: "pt", name: "Português", file: "pt.js" }
                ],
                defaultLocale: "en",
                lazy: true,
                langDir: "locales/",
                detectBrowserLanguage: false

                // vuex: {
                //  // Module namespace
                //  moduleName: 'translations',

                //  // If enabled, current app's locale is synced with nuxt-i18n store module
                //  syncLocale: true,

                //  // If enabled, current translation messages are synced with nuxt-i18n store module
                //  syncMessages: true,

                //  // Mutation to commit to set route parameters translations
                //  syncRouteParams: true
                // },
            }
        ],

        [
            "nuxt-fontawesome",
            {
                imports: [
                    {
                        set: "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons",
                        icons: ["fas"]
                    },
                    {
                        set: "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons",
                        icons: ["fab"]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    ],

    purgeCSS: {
        // your settings here
        whitelist: ["iframe", "is-disabled", "selected"],
        whitelistPatterns: [
            /(^|\.)ra/,
            /(^|\.)ru/,
            /(^|\.)rn/,
            /(^|\.)rf/,
            /(^|\.)lg/,
            /(^|\.)fa-/,
            /(^|\.)fn-/,
            /-fa($|\.)/,
            /(^|\.)fas-/,
            /-fas($|\.)/,
            /(^|\.)slick-/,
            /-bg2($|\.)/,
            /(^|\.)mgl-/,
            /(^|\.)mapboxgl-/,
            /(^|\.)hooper-/,
            /(^|\.)liked/,
            /(^|\.)flex-/,
        ]
    },

    /*
     ** Axios module configuration
     ** See https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options
     */
    axios: {
        // Testing... https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options
        //baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_DOMAIN || "http://localhost:8000"
        //proxy: true
        //prefix: 'http://localhost:8000/',
    },

    env: {
        apiDomain: process.env.VUE_APP_API_DOMAIN || "http://localhost:8000/api",
        cookieDomain: process.env.COOKIE_DOMAIN || "localhost",
        //cookieSecure: process.env.COOKIE_SECURE || false
        cookieSecure: false
    },

    sentry: {
        dsn: process.env.SENTRY_DSN || "", // Enter your project's DSN here
        config: {} // Additional config
    },

    /*
     ** Build configuration
     */
    build: {
        /*
         ** You can extend webpack config here
         */
        extend(config, ctx) {
            if (ctx.isDev) {
                config.devtool = ctx.isClient
                    ? "source-map"
                    : "inline-source-map";
            }
        },

        babel: {
            presets({ isServer }) {
                const targets = isServer ? { node: "current" } : { ie: 11 };
                return [
                    [require.resolve("@nuxt/babel-preset-app"), { targets }]
                ];
            }
        }
    }
};

/*
** Proxy won't be applicable in staging or prod, as all assets are absolute/full urls
*/
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    // Lambda DOES NOT LIKE proxy module load!
    nuxtConfig.modules.push("@nuxtjs/proxy");

    nuxtConfig.proxy = {
        "/media": { target: process.env.VUE_APP_API_DOMAIN || "http://localhost:8000" },
        "/objects": { target: process.env.VUE_APP_API_DOMAIN || "http://localhost:8000" }
    };
};

module.exports = nuxtConfig;
```

Any help much appreciated.